# Leaflet several featuregroups order changes when toggled

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am using Leaflet.js to create a map. The data displayed on the map depends on user selection so I instantiate two empty feature groups on map load, one for the values, and one for a color marker behind the value ( color depends on the value ).

```
if( dHMT.dataColorLayer===undefined ){
    dHMT.dataColorLayer = new L.featureGroup({}).addTo(dHMT.map);
}
if( dHMT.dataValueLayer===undefined ){
    dHMT.dataValueLayer = new L.featureGroup({}).addTo(dHMT.map);
}
```

I then add the empty layers to the layer switcher.

```
dHMT.overlayMapsLS = {
    "Bassins ": dHMT.bassinLayer,
    "Couleurs    ": dHMT.dataColorLayer,
    "Données    ": dHMT.dataValueLayer
};
```

Once the user selects data, the featureGroups are filled with the relevant values/markers.

```
    var iconColor = L.divIcon({className: 'dataSpans',html:"<div style='text-align: center;border-radius: 50%;height:40px;width:40px;padding-top:9px;background:"+dHMT.siteinfo[x].color+"'></div>"});
    var iconColorDiv = L.marker([dHMT.ecartArray[x].lat, dHMT.ecartArray[x].lon], {icon: iconColor})
            .bindPopup(
                'Nom :    '+dHMT.siteinfo[x].name+'<br>'+
                'Numéro : '+dHMT.siteinfo[x].stnm+'<br>'+
                'Stid :   '+dHMT.siteinfo[x].stid+'<br>'+
                'LatLon : '+dHMT.siteinfo[x].lat+','+dHMT.ecartArray[x].lon+'<br>'+
                'Valeur : '+dHMT.ecartArray[x].ecart+'<br>'
            ).on('mouseover', function (e) {
                this.openPopup();
            }).on('mouseout', function (e) {
                this.closePopup();
            });
    var iconValue = L.divIcon({className: 'dataSpans',html:"<div style='text-align: center;height:40px;width:40px;padding-top:9px;'>"+value+"</div>"});
    var iconValueDiv = L.marker([dHMT.ecartArray[x].lat, dHMT.ecartArray[x].lon], {icon: iconValue});               
    dataColorFeatures.push(iconColorDiv);
    dataValueFeatures.push(iconValueDiv);
    L.featureGroup(dataColorFeatures).addTo(dHMT.dataColorLayer);   
    L.featureGroup(dataValueFeatures).addTo(dHMT.dataValueLayer);
```

Both layers are fine, I have a nice map with a marker layer with colored circles with another layer displaying values over the marker. The goal being to deactivate the colors or the values using the layer switcher.

The problem is that if, for example, I toggle the color layer off, and turn it on again, the colored circles reappear over the values. The desired behavior would be to have them reappear in the original order, behind the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the `overlayadd` event on your `L.Map` instance:

> Fired when an overlay is selected through the layer control.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-overlayadd

When fired you can use the `bringToFront` method of `L.FeatureLayer`:

> Brings the layer group to the top of all other layers.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup-bringtofront

```
map.on('overlayadd', function () {
    dHMT.dataValueLayer.bringToFront();
});
```

Comment: Thnx for the quick reply! I see the 'overlayadd' event firing in the console, and I see the .bringToFront() in my dHMT.dataValueLayer, but for some reason it is not bringing it to front, I get the same result as before.

Comment: Weird. Perhaps you can try to use `bringToBack` on your `dHMT.dataColorLayer`?

Comment: I do agree it makes no sense, the function is there, it should work. BringtoBack() didn't do it either. However, I ended up using the event fired to clear both layers and re-add the features in the order I need which still works for me. I'll have a  look at why the bringToFront()/back() function wouldn't work another day, for now I have the desired result. Ty.